# Why can't I select an dropdown option in the C# WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, dom

I would like to change the selected option in a dropdown control, using the C# WebControl.

The html looks like this:

```
<select data-dropdownify-type="month" data-dropdownify-label="Maand" name="birthday.month">
    <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4" selected="selected">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
```

I tried to select an option using this code first:

```
br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("birthday.month")[0].SetAttribute("value", "2");
```

But it did not work out for me, I did not saw any errors tho but the selected option did not change.

So I started looking on the internet and found out there is another way to do this so then I tried to change the option with this code:

```
br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").GetElementsByName("birthday.month")[0].Children[2].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

But this did not work either! I again saw no error but the selected option did not change. Is there any other way I can do this? I thought maybe it has something to do with dropdownify but I am not sure.

Comment: you mean winforms webbrowser or a webcontrol? if you mean web browser, where are you putting the code to change the selected element? make sure it's in (or after) the DocumentCompleted event of the web browser control

Answer (score 0):

To select option from select element use `selectedIndex`. Here in this example unmanaged `MSHTML` library was used. HTH

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;

// This code was written under the assumption that your form has a 
// WebBrowser control named WebBrowser1, 
// and that you have added the unmanaged MSHTML library as a reference to your project.

namespace WebClientDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(<your-url-here>);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                                          WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
                return;
            IHTMLDocument2 iDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            HTMLSelectElement selectElement = iDoc?.all.OfType<HTMLSelectElement>()
                                   .FirstOrDefault(s => s.name == "birthday.month");
            if (selectElement != null)
            {
                selectElement.selectedIndex = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```